# Updating underlying data with Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau worksheet that displays data from an XLSX in a scatter plot.  Sometimes after plotting the data, I want to make manual adjustments.

Currently, I open the XLSX file in Excel and change the data - but I want to make the process more streamlined and edit the underlying data directly in Tableau is this possible?  I really wish that I could edit the text when I click on "View Data" after selecting a data point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tableau is not designed for editing the data, only visualizing it. You can do many powerful things within Tableau to transform data, but if you want directly change numbers and figures then the best way (and correct way) to do this is Excel.